# Prevent OS X from powering off, via CLI

Tags: macos, launchd

I use [`maid`](https://github.com/benjaminoakes/maid) to run a few maintenance scripts regularly, via `launchd`. The time I chose for those tasks to run makes it very likely that I won’t suddenly decide to turn off my computer around then, but one can never be absolutely certain.

Sometimes, GUI apps prevent the computer from turning off due to unsaved changes. Can we replicate this via CLI? A bit like [`caffeinate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/caffeinate.8.html) but for power off instead of sleep.

Answer (score 1):

How about actually using a GUI app to make an unsaved document?

```
osascript -e '
    tell application "TextEdit"
        activate
        set d to (make document)
        set text of d to "Your script is still running!"
    end tell
'
```

Comment: Too hacky and unreliable. Also hard to abort.

Comment: Hard to abort? Can’t you just close TextEdit?

Comment: Not programatically without closing the whole of TextEdit (which might contain legitimate documents).

Comment: Oh, programmatically. Well...maybe there's some way to return the document from AppleScript and store it for later use.

Answer (score -1):

the built in pmset utility can do this

```
sudo pmset autopoweroff 0
sudo pmset disksleep 0
```

Should work. If you want to see what all settings are available to `pmset`, and their currently set values:

```
pmset -g
```

You can also `man pmset` for more info on the pmset utility. Make sure to set the values back to their defaults after changing :)

Comment: Doesn’t work. I can still power off normally (even though the options did indeed change).

Comment: What are you trying to do? Prevent a manual shutdown of the system?

Comment: Yes. Like I said (emphasis added): “(…) suddenly **decide** to turn off my computer (…) GUI apps prevent the computer from turning off due to unsaved changes”. When do GUI apps typically do that other than when you’re trying to manually power off? If I only wanted to stop automatic power off, I’d use `caffeinate`, as mentioned.

Comment: Good luck finding your answer.